# SpEL expression breaks after Java upgrade - Is there an alternative?

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-el

I'm trying to split a String based on a comma separated delimiter.
Then check if the List of String after the split contains the String i'm looking for, i.e "ABCD"
Ex: getValueFromVendorFile() returns "EFGH,ABCD,GHJK"

The below SpEL expression evaluates to true with Java 6 and Spring framework 3.1.1.RELEASE

```
T(java.util.Arrays).asList(getValueFromVendorFile().split(',')).contains('ABCD')
```

On upgrade to Java 8 and Spring framework 4.3.7.RELEASE it evaluates to false

This is due the result being returned has now changed to an Object Array of ArrayList. Previously was returning just an ArrayList.

Tried the below fix , but the performance has taken a hit!

```java
T(org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils).arrayToList(getValueFromVendorFile().split(',')).contains('ABCD')
```

I expecting an ArrayList of type String but the actual output is an Array of ArrayList of type String due to which the expression fails.

Comment: *but the performance has taken a hit* - I seriously doubt that; also very interesting how you _know_ that or measured

Comment: I measured the performance by running a vendor file(2000 records) against old version (Java 6 / Spring 3.x) and the new version (Java 8 / Spring 4.x). Same file took ~20 mins to process on the old version where as ~2 hours on the new version.